# Short story published in a magazine about spider-women on an alien planet?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, spaceship

I'm hoping to locate an old sci-fi story I first heard about in an old New Yorker article by Margaret Atwood [http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2012/06/04/the-spider-women], in which she describes a sci-fi story she read in a magazine at around age 10.  That would put the magazine publishing in the late 40's-early 50's.  Any help greatly appreciated!   Here's the story as she remembers it:

"A spaceship has crashed on a distant planet and its all-male crew has survived. They are taken in charge by a society that appears to consist solely of beautiful women. These women are very nice to them, pampering them and feeding them luscious banquets. (This being the late forties, or possibly the early fifties, there’s no explicit mention of sex.) The men are happy. They loll about, getting no exercise, and they gain weight. They congratulate one another on never having had it so good.

"Then suddenly one day they’re put into a pen with a number of other men. These men are skinny.

“You fools,” the skinny men say, or words to that effect. “Don’t you know what’s happening tomorrow?” The now plump men are alarmed. It seems that it’s mating season, and the next day the men will be let out of their pen. They will try to run away very fast, and the beautiful women will chase them. When a woman catches a man—and, naturally, the plumper men will be slower, and also more attractive to the women, for reasons that will soon become clear—she will bite him on the neck, paralyzing him. Then she will lay her eggs on him.

"Too late the gourmands see the folly of their ways. The next day dawns. The gate opens. What can they do but waddle as fast as they can, huffing and puffing because they’re so out of shape? Meanwhile, the slender fellows scamper away, to live and run another day, we assume.

"The last part of the story was in italics and was a direct transmission from the mind of one of the women. It was a love song. She was filled with desire for the unfortunate and terrified gentleman she was pursuing, and especially for his larva-nourishing fatty tissues—a desire that was consummated, at the very end of the story, with a sigh of ecstasy and repletion."